# Download links in HTML not working with exe

Tags: html, file, hyperlink, download, exe

Ok i have to set a download link for a file on my website. But it NEVER WORKS.

I've tried this:

```
<a href="http://sitename.tk/downloads/exe/filename.exe" target="_blank"><button type="button">Download</button></a>
```

All that outputs is a blank page.

I've also tried:

```
<a href="http://sitename.tk/downloads/exe/filename.exe" download><button type="button">Download</button></a>
```

AND:
**When I tryed these last two it said file not found at www.sitename.tk/download/exe/filename.exe**

```
<a href="http://sitename.tk/downloads/exe/filename.exe" download="filename.exe"><button type="button">Download</button></a>

<a href="http://sitename.tk/downloads/exe/filename.exe" target="_blank" download="filename.exe"><button type="button">Download</button></a>
```

Can someone PLEASE help me. I've been programming html for years now and I can't get this one simple thing to work. Thank you in advance

*UPDATE*
I've triedit with mp3 and mp4 file types and those work fine
to do that I did this:

```
<a href="sitename.tk/downloads/mp3/song.mp3" download="mp3"><button type="button"></button></a>
```

But if I do this:

```
<a href="http://www.sitename.tk/downloads/exe/filename.exe" download="exe"><button type="button"></button></a>
```

It does not work

Comment: try href='sitename.tk....' with http at the start

Comment: @MIIB If you enclose your code with backticks (`), your comment won't show up as an actual link.

Answer (score 1):

You should use http:// before or else the client side browser will interpret `sitename.tk` as a subfolder. Try using this:
`<a href="http://sitename.tk/downloads/exe/filename.exe" target="_blank"><button type="button">Download</button></a>`

Comment: Thank you for your input but this did not work for me